# Passing a Retrofit2 response to an activity

Tags: android, oop, callback, retrofit

This is killing my eyes and will probably be the first thing you'll see. But it's too long I am trying to understand why this is not working. So here is the problem :

I use Retrofit 2 to get an object 'Userlogs'. Everything works fine.
When I print the Response.body() in the Log the object object seem to be perfectly parsed.

Then I set this object as a field of my class 'RepoUser_log' so that I get my object when I want.
When I want it, you'll ask ? ... it s ver simple , I want it in my mainActivity.

So lets go for the code :

```
public class RepoUser_log {

    private static APIService userService = ApiUtils.getAPIService();
    public   Userslogs userslogs = new Userslogs();
    public  List<Userslogs> listUserslogs = new ArrayList<>();

    public RepoUser_log(int IdPersonne){
        userslogs = CallBy(IdPersonne);
    }
    public Userslogs  CallBy(int iduser){
    Call<Userslogs> call = userService.GetUser(iduser);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Userslogs>() {

      @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Userslogs> call, Response<Userslogs> response) {
   Userslogs   userslogs = (Userslogs) response.body();
   Log.d( "onResponse: " , response.body().getEmail()); // works well here !
   Log.d("usersLog : ", userslogs.getEmail());  // that too Works well !  So my object exists and is well parsed
 }

      @Override
  public void onFailure(Call<Userslogs> call, Throwable t) {
              Userslogs  userslogs = null;
           }
       });
        return userslogs;
    }
}
```

Now here is my MainActivity when I want to use the object 'userlogs' I just got

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, NiveauFragment.OnMessageSendlistener{

    Userslogs userslogs;
    Joueur joueur;
    Personne personne;
    private View mProgressView;
    private static final String DATA_ID_PERSONNE = "idPersonne";
    int idPersonne;
    ServiceLocalisation serviceLocalisation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        idPersonne = intent.getIntExtra(DATA_ID_PERSONNE, idPersonne);

        RepoUser_log repoUser = new RepoUser_log(idPersonne);

        Log.d("doInBackground: ", repoUser.userslogs.getEmail()); // it fails here my object is null says the debugger
```

So for me it seems that it is less a problem with retrofit2 that my oop understanding.
But the function CallBy returning a userlog object that can't pass the frontiere of the function 'void onResponse' is a new thing....

Can someone help me... because I have many other stuff to get from retrofit :) that I don 't want to load from the activity itself.

Thank you.

Comment: your implementation is incorrect, when you call `call.enqueue`, its working on another thread so that why method CallBy return null value

Comment: Thank you Gianhtran ! It seems logic what you say. (I just hope you dont say that because you read ("doInbackground") (that is a remaining string of everychanged I made tonight ;)  ... but yea, if I use enque un one class, called by the main activity ... my response object can't probably be on time for the log.d in the mainActivity. That make sens. I am new in multithreading ... is there a function I could use to wait for the result in the mainActivity ? ... something like 'await'  in C# ?

Comment: please check my answer below :)

Comment: My solution is using a interface that will listen your api request and post a callback to your activity when your api success or fail

Comment: Ok, I think I understand a bit. I need a listener, and a function to call my response ... and then I should use both in the main. Yea, that should do it ... look I am very sorry , but I am very tired. I need to sleep it s 5 in the morning and I will continue to comunicate with you later in the day, but I really need to sleep :) Thank you !! I think that's the solution. :) thank you !

Comment: I leave a answer with detail code below, hope it helps, today and tomorrow I will offline, so nice to help you

Comment: Hi gianhtran, I 've founded the solution. Your diagnostic was good. it was effectivly a problem of 2 differents threads. But the solution was different : I had to change the function in the repo_userlogs to synchronuous functions. and then in the mainActivity to create a Runnable and a thread. ...So now I can retrieve everything I need from my repo to my activities. Thank you for your help !! Is there a way we can stay in touch on stackOverflow ?

Comment: hi Remi Duplan, Stackoverflow have no this feature, but you always find help from here, everybody always ready help you. It's sounds good when I hear that you find a solution, have a nice day !

Answer (score 0):

You are creating new object inside `onResponse` use the global variable there :

```
onResponse(Call<Userslogs> call, Response<Userslogs> response) {
   Userslogs   userslogs = (Userslogs) response.body();
   Log.d( "onResponse: " , response.body().getEmail()); // works well here !
   Log.d("usersLog : ", userslogs.getEmail());  // that too Works well !  So my object exists and is well parsed
 }
```

change :

`Userslogs   userslogs = (Userslogs) response.body();`

to

`userslogs = = (Userslogs) response.body();`

It shall work.

Comment: Hello Nilesh ! well, no it's not working. I just don't get how to my get response body in global field. (sorry continuing the sentence :) ). If i log.d the result inside the 'void on Response' function everything is perfect. The trouble starts when I want to put that body into a object of the same type. and use it outside this function. If i log.d the contains of the response.body just before the return ... same thing ... it becomes a null object.

Comment: Ok so I have advanced a bit : (and I am not sure why), but it seems that it is important to test if(response.isSuccessfull) {  functionToGetTheObject(response);  } and then you are at least out the onResponse function. No I need to get this field into my mainActivity ... which should be easy .... but  it's not

Answer (score 0):

as I commented above, your implementation is wrong, 
so I have a solution

```
public class RepoUser_log {

    private static APIService userService = ApiUtils.getAPIService();
    public List<Userslogs> listUserslogs = new ArrayList<>();
    public ApiListenner listenner;
    private int IdPersonne;

    public RepoUser_log(int IdPersonne) {
        this.IdPersonne = IdPersonne;
    }

    public void setListenner(ApiListenner listenner) {
        this.listenner = listenner;
    }

    public void callApi() {
        CallBy(IdPersonne)
    }

    public Userslogs CallBy(int iduser) {
        Call<Userslogs> call = userService.GetUser(iduser);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Userslogs>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Userslogs> call, Response<Userslogs> response) {
                if (listenner != null) listenner.onSuccess((Userslogs) response.body());
                Log.d("onResponse: ", response.body().getEmail()); // works well here !
                Log.d("usersLog : ",
                        userslogs.getEmail());  // that too Works well !  So my object exists and is well parsed
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Userslogs> call, Throwable t) {
                if (listenner != null) listenner.onFail(t);
            }
        });
        return userslogs;
    }

    public interface ApiListenner {
        void onSuccess(Userslogs userslogs);

        void onFail(Throwable t);
    }
}
```

in your activity

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        idPersonne = intent.getIntExtra(DATA_ID_PERSONNE, idPersonne);

        RepoUser_log repoUser = new RepoUser_log(idPersonne);

        repoUser.setListenner(new ApiListenner() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Userslogs userslogs) {
                Log.d("doInBackground: ", userslogs.getEmail()); // it fails here my object is null says the debugger
            }

            @Override
            public void onFail(Throwable t) {
                // api fail
            }
        });
        repoUser.callApi(); 

    }
```

Comment: Hi, (I am back after a good sleep), I've implemented your proposal as it is. and It's not working.